# how to handle edge case when using Java.time to convert date time to epoch

Tags: scala, java-time

This is my code which converts date time to epoch timestamp, there's one case that I don't know how to deal with, if zone info is included in the timestamp and not passed as the third argument to this function, it will always be converted to UTC despite what time zone is in the timestamp, how to solve this problem?

```
  time_to_epoch(List(JString("2007-12-03T10:15:30 CET"), JString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss z"))) shouldEqual JString("1196669730000")
```

time_to_epoch(List(JString("2007-12-03T10:15:30+02:00"), JString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"), JString("CEST"))) shouldEqual JString("1196669730000")
time_to_epoch(List(JString("2007-12-03T10:15:30 CEST"), JString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss z"))) shouldEqual JString("1196673330000")

```
 whatever timezone in the timestamp, the result is wrong, i.e, CEST(+02:00), output (+01:00), America/Mexico_City(+05:00), output (+04:00)
```

Comment: If you don't want to loos information about a time zone use `ZonedDateTime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If timezone data can be a part of the `timestamp` string then you should probably let that override the `timezone` string whether it was supplied by default or not.

```
formatter.parseBest(timestamp, ZonedDateTime.from _
                             , LocalDateTime.from _
                             , LocalDate.from _) match {
  case zdt: ZonedDateTime =>
    JString(zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli.toString)
  case ldt: LocalDateTime =>
    . . .
```

Comment: I tried it, but these two cases have different result..(edited the code)

Comment: @zzxdw; You've incorporated my answer into the question code and then changed the focus of the question. You've added test examples without including the results you're getting. (My test code passes both.) Please focus each question to _one_ problem with clear concise code demonstrating the _one_ problem.